# Importance of parents in value education - shlokas and instances

Tags: puranas, shloka, story, family

What are some shlokas and incidents from scriptures that show the importance of mother and father in value education of child?

For example, I can faintly recall one incident about a mother who sang to her children 'Tat Tvam Asi' or something similar in place of the usual lullaby and the children grew up to be sages.

Similarly, I came across this shloka "Mata shatru, pita vairi, yen balo na pathitah" (mother is an enemy and father a foe if they do not educate their child)

Please give a collection of such incidents and shlokas in your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The story you are referring to is that of Madalasa found in the Markandeya Purana.

Comment: Within the varnashrama system, parents didn't had much role in educating their child, for that part was reserved for the guru. Upanayana in Vaidika culture also marked the departure of the child for the gurukula, where the the guru was responsible for imparting both religious & secular (music, medicine, grammar, astrology, poetry, weaponry, statecraft) education. Samavartana marked the return of the child from gurukula & was quickly followed by vivaha. Since shudras were banned from undergoing brahmacharya, they instead learned their family occupation from their parents.

Comment: Regarding imparting of values, the scriptures allot that duty to brahmanas in general & the king to ensure that they are being upheld. The role of parents is very minimal in this system.

Comment: @অনু Alright. Thanks for telling me!